# TaskScheduler RegisterTaskDefinition fails with (38:4)UserID

Tags: windows, winapi, scheduled-tasks

I am using the Task Scheduler 2.0 API to create a scheduled task.

[Following the MSDN code example (for creating a time-triggered task)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383624(v=vs.85).aspx), i call the COM objects myself:

```
ITaskService taskService = new TaskScheduler();
taskService.Connect("", "", "", "");

ITaskDefinition task = taskService.NewTask(0); //flags reserved and must be zero
task.RegistrationInfo.Author = "Me";
task.Principal.LogonType := TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN;

ITimeTrigger = task.Triggers.Create(TASK_TRIGGER_TIME) as ITimeTrigger;
trigger.Id = "Trigger1";
trigger.StartBoundary = "2017-03-14T16:30:00";

IExecAction action = task.Actions.Create(TASK_ACTION_EXEC) as IExecAction;
action.Path = "Notepad.exe";

ITaskFolder folder = taskService.GetFolder("\");

folder.RegisterTaskDefinition("MyTaskName", task, TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
      Null, Null, TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN, "");
```

> **Note:** The above code was transcoded from Delphi; so as to not scare people away with a syntax they're not used to.

In Task Scheduler 2.0 all tasks are really just Xml. You can view the xml of the task definition just before registering it:

> `task.XmlText;`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Author>Me</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <TimeTrigger id="Trigger1">
      <StartBoundary>2017-03-14T16:30:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <Duration>PT10M</Duration>
      <WaitTimeout>PT1H</WaitTimeout>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions>
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Attempting to register that Task XML throws the COM exception:

> (38,4):UserId

## Credentials

The MSDN example is very specific in their use of

- **LogonType**: `TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN`
- **UserId**: *none*
- **Password**: *none*
- **SDDL** *(security descriptor list)*: `""`

### Question

How do you register a scheduled task with the Task Scheduler 2.0 COM object API?

### Look at the answer in the back of the book and work forward

No code example anywhere deals with `UserId`. But if i manually create a task in the task scheduler, and export it to XML:

[image]

I *can* find a `UserId` element inside a `Principles` element:

```
<Principals>
  <Principal id="Author">
    <UserId>S-1-5-21-1708537768-854245398-2146844275-1109</UserId>
    <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
    <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
  </Principal>
</Principals>
```

Even though my code (and the MSDN example) both call:

**MSDN**:

```
//  Set up principal logon type to interactive logon
pTask->get_Principal( &pPrincipal );
pPrincipal->put_LogonType( TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN );
```

**Me**:

```
task.Principal.LogonType := TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN;
```

Mine doesn't work. What gives?

And even if i do have to figure out a user's Sid:

- why does the MSDN sample not have to?
- why does [this guy not have to](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/02/23/calling-the-task-scheduler-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008-from-managed-code.aspx)

What gives?

### Another MSDN sample

The canonical MSDN Example only sets:

```
task.Principal.LogonType := TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN;
```

[Another example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382113(v=vs.85).aspx) sets:

```
task.Principal.Id := 'Principle1';
task.Principal.LogonType := TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN;
task.Principal.RunLevel := TASK_RUNLEVEL_LUA;
```

Which then adds *Principle* related element to the final XML:

```
<Principals>
  <Principal id="Principle1">
    <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
  </Principal>
</Principals>
```

But still fails:

```
(15,8):UserId
```

for my new Xml:

```
 1: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
 2: <Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
      ...
12:   <Principals>
13:     <Principal id="Principle1">
14:       <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
15:     </Principal>
16:   </Principals>
      ...
43: </Task>
```

### Bonus Reading

- Example code on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/282060/4822)
- [Example article](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/02/23/calling-the-task-scheduler-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008-from-managed-code.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For people coming here from google looking on how to fix `(x:x)UserID` error, in my case it meant that the `UserId` defined on the `Task` was not equivalent to the `UserId` in the system.
So the following code (the last line) is what fixed my issue:

```
    TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
    td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";
    td.Principal.UserId = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```